# Share as file on filesystem?

Tags: file-system, files, share-menu

Various apps have a "share" functionality which opens up several providers of media/means to share some piece of content (e.g. send over WhatsApp and many others). Is it possible to have a "sharing provider" which simply saves the shared content as a file on the device filesystem?

My main interest is sharing text, but not just that. I don't particularly care about the encoding/structural format - but do say something about that if you can.

Comment: As you might know, to have a "sharing target", there must be an app providing it. A file manager app might offer that. Can't tell you which one does.

Comment: @Izzy: I was hoping there's some kind of shim app that's just intended to allow saving to file.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry. To my knowledge, neither exists a way do achieve that without any app at all.

Comment: Try MiXplorer. It can copy shared text to clipboard and save shared files to filesystem. I've a similar app of my own which can do more but that isn't ready for public release.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Please write an answer suggesting that, and: 1. Compare it with the apps I've suggested in my answer; 2. Explain whether it's available for MI devices only or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is definitely possible!

My recommended tool to accomplish this is [Solid Explorer File Manager by NeatBytes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2).

In addition to being a great file manager, it also creates a ***Share target*** named `"Save to..."` for saving any content as a file in your storage.  I've personally used it for this purpose hundreds of times, and it works quite well.

Another tool that may interest you is the wonderful [ShareListener by Red Apps LTD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.laurencedawson.sharelistener).  It's a simple tool without any UI of it's own that is:

> A simple app that registers itself as a Browser. When opened, the link is then shared and can be opened with any apps that listen for the share intent.
>
> Useful for apps that don't have a share functionality but allow users to click on links.

*Source: Google Play store description.*

Since it needs no primary UI of its own, here is how it looks to the user:

[image: ShareListener screenshot]

*Source: Google Play store screenshot.*

The magic of ShareListener is that when you try to share a link.  Many apps will only allow you to open a browser.  ShareListener will allow you to share links with non-browser apps, including Solid Explorer!  When used in conjunction with Solid Explorer's ***Share target***, you can quickly save any link to storage instead of opening it in a browser.

Comment: Can you compare "SolidExplorer" with the apps mentioned in the other answers? Anyway, +1.

Comment: @einpoklum I've use X-plore by Lonely Cat Games, and IIRC, it works similarly to the **Share target** in Solid Explorer. Although X-plore is quite good, I find it better for tablets (vs. phones) due to the amount of data it shows within its UI (Solid Explorer has a cleaner approach, but both apps are excellent). I don't have an Xiaomi phone to test their proprietary File Manager, but I do try not to rely on proprietary solutions (makes it easier to change brands at any time). The helpful functionality of the ShareListener tool I recommended is not provided by any of the other tools mentioned.

Comment: ShareListener is now a broken link

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two such apps/sharing providers that I am aware of.

The first and less universally-relevant is available on newer Xiaomi phones; it is the File Manager application (or one closely related to it); in the "Share..." options, it appears as a yellowish folder, with the caption "Copy To". When chosen, it lets you select among the internal storage, (possibly) any SD card, and some remote options which are irrelevant to this question. After having navigated to a relevant folder, you press the Paste button available at the bottom of your screen.

The more universally-relevant option is an application called [X-plore](https://www.lonelycatgames.com/apps/xplore/), by [Lonely Cat Games](https://www.lonelycatgames.com/). It's also a kind of file manager app, which feels a bit more Norton-Commander-ish with a single pane than Windows-Explorer-ish. Its icon has a silvery wrench over a dark-gray-and-organe background, and the caption is also "Copy To". You then use the X-plore file tree UI to choose where to write the file.

This was all reported based on behaviors on my own phone, which is currently a MI 9 SE.

Answer (score 1):

[Send to SD card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gelin.android.sendtosd&hl=en&gl=US) is a very simply app that does exactly that. Not updated since 2015 unfortunately.

I also found [Share to File System](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxhead.android.sharetofilesystem&hl=en&gl=US) which I haven't tried and has only 1k downloads and last updated 2018.